# Generating function of this sequence

Tags: generating-functions

Find the generating function of the sequence with the property $\sum_{i=0}^n a_{i}a_{n-i} = 1$. I'm not sure where to start in this problem.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* If $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ is a formal power series
then 
$$
 f(x)^2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{i=0}^n  a_{i}a_{n-i} \right) x^n
$$
(See [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).)
In your case, the right-hand side is a well-known infinite series.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n.\tag{1} $$
Cauchy's convolution hence gives:
$$ f(x)^2 = \sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i a_{n-i}\right) x^n = \sum_{n\geq 0} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}\tag{2} $$
and we have $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$, from which:
$$ a_n = \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}(-1)^n=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n\,n!}=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.\tag{3} $$